# Vector3.z initialize as a positive but then go negative without any script modification

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build some hexagonal mesh and, as I was just trying to visualize with OnDrawGizmos some minimalist hexagon with 7 Vector3 vertices, something weird happened, because only five appears, missing the two from the top. And if I delete the last two vertices, the two top-ones show up immediately.

So I wrote in console the value of all my vertices and surprise, the first two have the same value as the last two, althought they aren't the same when I declare them :

```
hexVertices[0][0] = new Vector3(-outR/2f, 0, innR);
hexVertices[0][1] = new Vector3(outR/2f, 0, innR);
hexVertices[1][0] = new Vector3(-outR, 0, 0);
hexVertices[1][1] = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
hexVertices[1][2] = new Vector3(outR, 0, 0);
hexVertices[2][0] = new Vector3(-outR / 2f, 0, -innR);
hexVertices[2][1] = new Vector3(outR / 2f, 0, -innR);
```

Which gives me :

```
(-0.5, 0.0, -0.9)
(0.5, 0.0, -0.9)
(-1.0, 0.0, 0)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(-0.5, 0.0, -0.9)
(0.5, 0.0, -0.9)
```

...Altought the first two ones should have a positive z. I first thought that, as my vertices are store in three arrays which I merge after declaring the vertices, maybe the problem's there, but it isn't. So I just wrote the value of my two vertices between every line to see where that inversion occurs, and it seems that when hexVertices[2][0] is declared, then hexVertices[0][0].z is inverted, and the same is for hexVertices[0][1].z when hexVertices[2][0] is declared.

Is this some kind of weird memory issue or am I totally missing something there ?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53486337/edit) your question and include any code you use to declare/initialize `hexVertices`. Also, I'm curious what will print if you replace the last two asssignments with `hexVertices[2][0] = new Vector3(1f,2f,3f); hexVertices[2][1] = new Vector3(4f,5f,6f);` I think you might have made a shallow copy of `hexVertices[0]` without realizing it.

Comment: Oh yep that's it, the problem isn't when I declare hexVertices but just after when I declare the size of the sub-arrays. Because their lenght are symetrics I did well that : 
hexVertices[i] = hexVertices[nbLines - 1 - i] = new Vector3[nbVerticesMin + i];
So now it's fixed, thanks a lot - and I'm going to read again that chapter on value and references types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have it solved but I'm going to go ahead and write an answer so the question can be marked solved.

A good rule of thumb is to use one `new` for each independent copy you want to make.

Separating the line into two will fix your problem:

```
hexVertices[i] = new Vector3[nbVerticesMin + i];
hexVertices[nbLines - 1 - i] = new Vector3[nbVerticesMin + i];
```